# Finding a duplicate entry in MySQL from a certain date

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicate-data

I have a huge database containing over 10 million entries.

I would like to find duplicates in that table and therefore I am using the following statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM `customer_positions_all`
WHERE `position_id` IN (
    SELECT `position_id`
    FROM `customer_positions_all`
    GROUP BY `position_id`
    HAVING count(`position_id`) > 1
    )
ORDER BY `position_id`
```

I also have a "date" column, and I would like to only find the dups which are higher than a certain date (for example: `date` > '2014-04-01').

I am not sure where do I put it inside the query... I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `WHERE` clause before `GROUP BY` to use it with a `GROUP BY`. However, you can just do the filtering in the outer query, to filter from the list of IDs which are known to have duplicates like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM `customer_positions_all`
WHERE `position_id` IN (
SELECT `position_id`
FROM `customer_positions_all`
--WHERE date > '2014-04-01' --Redundant!
GROUP BY `position_id`
HAVING count(`position_id`) > 1
)
AND date > '2014-01-01'
ORDER BY `position_id`
```

Comment: It still takes too long...

Should't I also add it to the outer query?

Comment: @JacobCohen You are right, in fact it should be used in the outer query itself. I have edited my answer.

Comment: This took around 10% of the original time. Works.